# How would I append to my existing buffer array when my readstream gets new data?

Tags: javascript, node.js, buffer, filestream, fs

This question is kind of awkward, so I'll just post my code and say what it's doing and what I want it to do.

```
var fs = require('fs');

var myReader = fs.createReadStream('file.tsv', { 
    flags: 'r',
    encoding: 'UTF-8',
    fd: null,
    mode: 0666,
    bufferSize: 64 * 1024,
    autoClose: true
});

myReader.on('data', function(data){

    var array = (array || data.split(/[\n]/));

    // Parse and print array

})
```

This works completely fine as long as there's only one chunk, any more than that, and my data can or will get split in the middle of a line.

I'm trying to keep the same array, and append a new chunk to it. The code above doesn't represent an attempt at that, but I've tried a few with `+=` and `array.concat(data.split(/[\n]/))` and I've not had much success.

So how can I keep the same array for parsing, and just append the new data to it as becomes available?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var t = "";
    myReader = fs.createReadStream(file, {
            flags: 'r',
            encoding: 'UTF-8',
            fd: null,
            mode: 0666,
            bufferSize: 128 * 1024,
            autoClose: true
        })

    myReader.addListener("data", function (chunk) {
            t += chunk;

        })
```